# How to reuse NSMenu in different windows?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsmenu

In Xcode I've created a new Main Menu xib from the *Main Menu* template. It only contains the main-menu, which I would like to use in my app.

How can I load this *Main Menu* from this xib-file and use it in my different windows?

Comment: “I've created a new Main Menu xib from the Main Menu template.” What version of Xcode are you using? I haven't checked for this in Xcode 5, but they killed it off in Xcode 4, presumably because you can only have one Main Menu and so there isn't much reason to have multiple Main Menu nibs. Normally, you should just use the Main Menu that came with the project template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.

An application's main menu is already global—it's part of the application, not of any individual window. The same menus will appear regardless of which window is active, by default.

You would have to put in some work if you wanted to go the other way and have different menus depending on which window is active.